# calling an API in socket program?

Tags: c, api, sockets, operating-system, ip

```
void CreateSocket()
{
struct sockaddr_in server, client;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int len;
int iResult;

    printf("Initializing Winsock\n");


    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD (1, 1);
    iResult =  WSAStartup (wVersionRequested, &wsaData);      
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
   printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n"); 


    // create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0)    {
        printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
        //return 0;
    }

    printf("Socket Created\n");  


    // create socket address of the server
    memset( &server, 0, sizeof(server));


    // IPv4 - connection
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // accept connections from any ip adress
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    // set port
    server.sin_port = htons(52428);


    //Binding between the socket and ip address
    if(bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }


    //Listen to incoming connections
    if(listen(sock, 3) == -1){
        printf("Listen failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Server has been successfully set up - Waiting for incoming connections");

        len = sizeof(client);
        fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

        if(fd < 0)
        {
            printf("Accept failed\n");
        }
        printf("\n Process incoming connection from (%s , %d)", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),ntohs(client.sin_port));



}


int main()
{

    HANDLE h1,h2,h3;



double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;


CreateSocket();

 Xcp_Initialize();

     while(1)
        {
        if(fd == -1)
        {
            printf("Socket error\n ");
        }
        else

        {
             recv(fd, recv_data, 99, 0);
            //  pChunkData = &recv_data;
            //chunkLen = sizeof(pChunkData);
            //XcpIp_RxCallback ((uint16) chunkLen, (char*) pChunkData, (uint16) port);

        }
        }


        }
```

the above is a server program :
I am creating a socket with ip address and port number. I am accepting a connection from the client and recieving tha data from the client. I have to call the API : XcpIp_RxCallback ((uint16) chunkLen, (char*) pChunkData, (uint16) port);  when it receives a data on the port. Could anyone tell me where to call the API in the above program ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recvfrom function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  and then call XcpIp_RxCallback

The code looks something like

```
 iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket,RecvBuf, 
     BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) & SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);

 if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
     wprintf(L"recvfrom failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
 } else {
     XcpIp_RxCallback ((uint16) iResult, (char*) RecvBuf, (uint16)htons(SenderAddr.sin_port));
 }
```

Comment: Why use recvfrom()? The sender address for the socket doesn't change, and it is provided by accept().